# DefaultConversionService fails to convert property to list

Tags: java, spring, properties, data-conversion

```
some.property=1,2,3,4,5

@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultConversionService();
}

@Value("${some.property}")
final List<Integer> ints;
```

with this setup I'm getting `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,2,3,4,5"`

Question:

1. Why it treats property as `String.class` and ignores explicit class type `List<Integer>`?
2. Is there a way to convert to correct `List<Integer>` without implementing custom `ConversionService.convert` method?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Works for me without defining anything additionaly.

Comment: Remove the bean (the `conversionService`) and restart the application.